# Verification epsilon definition of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I would like to verify whether or not the following statements regarding the epsilon definition of a sequence is correct:

Regarding the first part $\left( \frac{|a_o-b|+...+|a_{M1-1}-b|}{m+1} \right)$ of a certain sequence $\left( \frac{|a_0-b|+...+|a_m-b|}{m+1} \right)$  with $\forall m\geq M_1$
Intuitively, when looking at the first part, note that you can view the numerator as a constant (now called $C$), I see that because $M_1$ is fixed, when you take m big enough you can make the whole first part smaller than a chosen epsilon ($\epsilon>0$). The difficulty for me is writing this down in a mathematically correct way.

Is the following reasoning correct?

We want $\left|\frac{C}{m+1}\right|<\epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{C}{m+1}<\epsilon$

Therefor take $M_2= \left\lceil \frac{C}{\epsilon } \right\rceil$ now:
$$ \left|\frac{C}{m+1}-0\right|= \left|\frac{C}{m+1}\right|=\frac{C}{m+1}<\frac{C}{m}\leq\frac{C}{M_2}<\frac{C}{\left\lceil \frac{C}{\epsilon}\right\rceil}<\frac{C}{ \frac{C}{\epsilon}}<\epsilon  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for some mistakes regarding $\leq$ and < , the idea of this part of the proof is confirmed by an assistent a the university.